# What is the range of $\arcsin(\sqrt {x^2 + x + 1}) $?

Tags: calculus, functions

I've tried the inequality method but it is not working for me.Help will be appreciated.

Comment: You problem statement is self-contained.  Start by giving the domain of $x$.  This is related to the range of subexpression $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$, from which you can determine the range of the expression in the title.  However all this detail should be presented in the body of the Question, and one should not rely entirely on the title to carry the burden of the problem statement.  The body should be more explicit in saying what "the inequality method" is and what about this did not work for you.

Comment: Thanks man.I'm  new to this community. Will keep these things in mind from next question onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, we need $-1\le\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\le1$

Now $x^2+x+1=\dfrac{(2x+1)^2+3}4\ge\dfrac34$

So, $\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\le\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\le1$

As $\arcsin(x)$ is increasing in  $[-1,1]$

$\implies\arcsin\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\le\arcsin\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\le\arcsin1$

Now $\arcsin\dfrac{\sqrt3}2=\dfrac\pi3$

Now the domain: $x^2+x+1\le1\iff x(x+1)\le0\iff-1\le x\le0$